# Loop through array and match items to html elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

I am looking for a more intuitive way to run the code below (as it is also incomplete to my purpose).

```
for (j = 0; j<items.length; j++) {
            var indivItem = items[j];
               if (indivItem.category == 1) {
                  $('.indiv_category[idnumber="1"]').append('<ul class="left_side_item"><li>'+indivItem.title+'</li></ul>');
               }
               else if (indivItem.category == 2) {
                  $('.indiv_category[idnumber="2"]').append('<ul class="left_side_item"><li>'+indivItem.title+'</li></ul>');
               }
            }
```

Essentially I need line 3 to check `if (indivItem.category > 0)` then look for the element with a matching `idnumber` attribute and append the necessary info.

I need this continue for the length of available `.indiv_category` elements.

Basically a matchup of the all items in the 'items' `array` to all of the elements with a matching 'idnumber' attribute to the item in the array that contains the same id number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remmove the condition and just use the variable `items[j].category` in selector.

```
for (j = 0; j<items.length; j++) {             
    $('.indiv_category[idnumber="'+ items[j].category + '"]').append('<ul class="left_side_item"><li>'+indivItem.title+'</li></ul>');             
}
```